# mkdir(): Permission denied when running php via XAMPP/Apache

Tags: php, apache, permissions, xampp, mkdir

I'm having an issue with uploading images in a PHP project, using `mkdir()`. The permission to create any directory is being denied. When I try this without using Apache and using the built-in `php -S` server on mac, the directory is created with no hassle.

```
if (!is_dir('images')) {
    mkdir('images');
  }

  if ($image && $image['tmp_name']) {
    $imagePath = 'images/' . randomString(8) . '/' . $image['name'];
    mkdir(dirname($imagePath));
    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $imagePath);
  }
```

I keep getting these errors to the above code:

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/KhqnrHx0/image.png): failed to open stream 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpmYtqa7' to 'image.png'

When I run `<?php echo 'whoami';?>` the result returns daemon and not my username, so I assume this is the reason why the permission is constantly denied, but I have no idea how to change permissions safely/properly.

Is anyone able to resolve this?

Comment: You need to give permission to script to use that directory, like in Linux we assign www-data as user and group to the directory.

Answer (score -1):

You guessed it: a permissions issue. How to set permissions depends on your environment, and you've not told us much.

I see you've got /opt/lampp, so from that I'm devising a linux stack. But which flavour? Centos? Debian? Puppy Linux? Who knows?

Getting you up to speed now will be a matter of going to your directory that you want to make the images directory in and setting its owner to (your apache user) and its permissions to probably 755. That will get the first bit working. Then you'll need to set the umask.